# Print all the combinations for a numeric array in java

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation, combinations

I have an int[10] array.
each slot of the array must be in the range [0,30] and I'd like to generate all the combinations. How can I do it? Its maybe easy but I'm a little stuck
by the way I used:

```
int[] array=new int[10];
for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    for (int j=0;i<30;j++){
        print(array);
    }
}
```

but doesn't print all the combinations.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations

Comment: Okay, so you know that that's 30 045 015 combinations, right?

Comment: yep I know thats a lot of combinations =)

Comment: Wouldn't it actually be 31!/(31-10)! ?

Comment: I think there are only 3,628,800 ways to arrange the 10 elements - that is, 10!

Comment: However, there are 30^10 possible ways to initialize the array.

Comment: @LloydOzymandiasForce - the question asks for *combinations* not *permutations*.  `N!` is the number of permutations of `N` elements.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what the problem is. There's the problem of initializing the array and then there's the problem of the permutations (which is N!, or in this case, 10!, as I stated above). So I guess combined you have 30^10 * 10! ... but I may be missing something still! And I refuse to get out paper, pencil, or an old math book! LOL

Answer (score 0):

you need to add elements to that array. the first loop gives you in the inner access to a variable i, the second for j, but to fill it I would first prefer a recursive way:

create a method with variables for your array and an index (which location to fill next in the array). Then call the method with a new array and index = 0

in the method 1. check if the index is already out of the array range. in that case print the array and exit the method
2. in all other cases, add a for loop from 0 to 30, and inside, add the current number to the location 'index' and call the method again, giving your array and index+1

but i would try that method with less items first. May take a while to print all

Here an example in vb.net language. You can not directly copy paste it, but it may help to understand how to create the combinations.

```
Private Sub AllCombinations(array() As Integer, index As Integer)
  If index < 10 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To 30
      array(index) = i
      AllCombinations(array, index + 1)
    Next
  Else
    PrintMethod(array.ToString)
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub AllPermutations(array() As Integer, index As Integer, remaining As List(Of Integer))
  If index < 10 Then
    For Each ele In remaining
      array(index) = ele
      Dim newRemaining As New List(Of Integer)
      newRemaining.AddRange(remaining)
      newRemaining.Remove(ele)
      AllPermutations(array, index + 1, newRemaining)
    Next
  Else
    PrintMethod(array.ToString)
  End If
End Sub
```

index 0..9 is t ofill array, if index is 10 then the array is full and we will only show it. Either we fill every slot with any number between 0 and 30, or you keep a list to memorize which numbers are still remaining (in the Permutations you need to fill the remaining list with all allowed numbers first!)

Comment: Not sure I follow you--why would you *fill* the array recursively? And AFAICT there's 10 numbers in the array, each between 0-30; there's no reason to loop 30 times for anything. The only thing worth recursing is to generate the combinations.

Comment: Was not asked for filling (generate all combinations)?fill it recursively, because that way it is much less program code and more easy to change.

Comment: Hm, I think I misunderstood the question, actually; thought the OPmmeant something else.

Comment: Hmm maybe you can clarify one thing in your question: the array 1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6 would be one of those combinations? Or is every number within that array only one time allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm described by Kenneth H. Rosen, *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 2nd edition* (NY: McGraw-Hill, 1991), pp. 284-286 : [CombinationGenerator - Java](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/au/edu/qut/yawl/editor/analyser/CombinationGenerator.java.html) (link updated)

Enjoy,